# Uploading file to Server host using sftp

Tags: c#, file, sockets, sftp

I'm currently getting this error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Net.SocketsExceptions: No such host is
>   known...

Not too sure what that means but this is what I did.

```
public FileUploader(/*string host, string port, string username, string password,*/ string fileLocation)
    {
      string temp;
      Console.Write("Server URL:");
      this.host = Console.ReadLine();
      Console.Write("Server Port:");
      temp = Console.ReadLine();
      this.port = int.Parse(temp);
      Console.Write("Username:");
      this.username = Console.ReadLine();
      Console.Write("Password:");
      this.password = ReadPassword();
      Console.Write("Folder Location:");
      this.fileLocation = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public void UploadFile(string pathToFile)
    {
      var client = new SftpClient(host, port, username, password);
      client.Connect();
      var fileStream = new FileStream(pathToFile, FileMode.Open);
      client.BufferSize = 4 * 1024;
      client.UploadFile(fileStream,fileLocation, null);
      client.Disconnect();
      client.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Likely the address you are using is incorrect or malformed.  Consult the documentation for whatever SftpClient is.

Comment: What's the value of `host`?

Comment: host is of this format: "http://********.*****.***.com"

Comment: That's HTTP, not SFTP. SFTP addresses start with `sftp`

Comment: I was given that for the server url has well 22 for the port is this wrong? And is there a way of geting the sftp url from the server itself?

Comment: Try passing the host name without any prefix `"bla.bla.com"`

Comment: hold on there might be an issue with the username/password

Comment: alright got it working it was the removing the prefix @Alex.K thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problems when I was including "ftp://" and "sftp://" in the **host name**.  And in my search google landed me here. This was because I switched from FtpWebRequest to **SSH.Net**, where my host value was previously a url.

I include the below code as an example for a working host name value.  Other people may also use an IP address instead.

```
const string sFtpHost = "someprefix.somedomain.com";
const int sFtpPort = 22;
const string userName = "SomeUser";
const string password = "SomePassword";

// ...

string localFileName = SomeFileName;
string remoteFileName = @"/SomeSubFolder/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(localFileName);

using (var sftp = new SftpClient(sFtpHost, sFtpPort, userName, password))
{
    sftp.Connect();

    using (var file = File.OpenRead(localFileName))
    {
        sftp.UploadFile(input: file, path: remoteFileName, canOverride: true);
    }

    sftp.Disconnect();
}
```

Comment: which client it is for sftp?

Comment: @James123 SSH.Net contains an SFTP Client.  https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/blob/develop/src/Renci.SshNet/SftpClient.cs
 You can use NuGet Package Manager to add the package for SSH.Net